# How to use QuickCheck in Hspec tests?

Tags: haskell, tdd, cabal, quickcheck, property-testing

I build the initial codebase for my Haskell project with `cabal init`
I have several tests written with Hspec.
On `cabal test` it compiles and runs these tests like expected and gives a message for failing/passing.

Now I included a **quickCheck** test and even when this test fails the output in terminal don't recognize the quickCheck test.

But in the dist/test/ dir i can see the test log `*** Failed! ...`

Is there a way to "include" quickCheck tests in the test workflow. So that i don't have to look on the test log after every test run.

```
import Test.Hspec
import Test.QuickCheck

spec :: Spec
spec = do
    describe "myTest" $ do
        it "Something something" $ do
            myTest "" `shouldBe` False
            quickCheckWith stdArgs { maxSuccess = 1000 } prop_myTest -- <== ?
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want the [property](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-12.4/QuickCheck-2.11.3/Test-QuickCheck.html#v:property) function, see [here](https://hspec.github.io/quickcheck.html).

Example:

```
spec :: Spec
spec = do
    describe "myTest" $ do
        it "Something something" $
            property prop_myTest
```